# How much does Ext tell me about isomorphisms?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, short-exact-sequences, group-rings, extension

So this was a question I sort of stumbled on and realised I was quite stumped. Suppose we have two finitely generated $R$-modules  $M, N$ (I have the group ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[G]$ in mind) which appear in short exact sequences

$$0\to X\to M\to Y\to 0,$$

$$0\to X\to N\to Y\to 0.$$

I know that $M$ and  $N$ are indecomposable and I know that ${\rm Ext}^1(Y, X)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2 \Bbb Z$. Are $M$ and  $N$ isomorphic?

If I can find a homomorphism between them which fits into a commutative diagram, then obviously this is true. But must such a homomorphism exist?

Comment: Don't you mean $Ext^1(Y,X)$ ?

Comment: ext(X,Y) classifies sequences 0->Y->M->X->0. If it was the other way I think you are OK.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. My bad.

Comment: Shouldn't your question be how much Ext tells you about *isomorphism* (as an adjective) of modules, not about *isomorphic* modules, since the point is to deduce, not to assume, the modules are isomorphic?

Comment: @LSpice yes, sorry. I should have thought more on the wording of this question. First time posting, so I didnt think. My own stupid fault.

Comment: So $M$ and $N$ are indecomposable. In particular these short exact sequences are nonsplit, so they correspond to non-zero elements of $\operatorname{Ext}^1(Y,X)$. If $\operatorname{Ext}^1(Y,X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, this means that these two sequences are equivalent, and in particular $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @spin that was exactly my logic, however I wasnt sure since I am not wholly comfortable with ext. I need to read more on it. It also seemed to me that they would be isomorphic if they belonged to inverse classes. However once again I was not sure of this.

Comment: Well, $x \mapsto -x$ *is* the identity map on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so being in inverse classes is the same as being in the same class! Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean? The important point is that $M$ and $N$ being indecomposable implies that neither extension corresponds to the identity element in $\text{Ext}^1$, and there is only one non-identity element in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Small note: this implication isn't entirely trivial, you need to use the fact that if $X = 0$ or $Y = 0$ then we would have $\text{Ext}^1(Y,X) = 0 \neq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk sorry, I was unclear. I meant if ext was $\mathbb{Z}/3$, for example. Then would that mean that any two indecomposable modules in an exact sequence $0\to X\to ?\to Y\to 0$ are still isomorphic? This just seems too good to be true. I suppose I am still unhappy with exactly how powerful ext is at classifying extensions (and how that relates to the modules). Could you also explain your small note further, please. Which implication do you mean?

Comment: Ah, yes, the assumption that $\text{Ext} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ is very strong and it is what allows us to conclude that any two non-split extensions are equivalent. If $\text{Ext} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3$ this will not be the case, however, any two non-split extensions *will* still be isomorphic, as you suspected! This is because if $0 \to X \xrightarrow{f} Z \xrightarrow{g} Y \to 0$ represents an element $a \in \text{Ext}^1(Y,X)$, then $-a$ is represented by $0 \to X \xrightarrow{-f} Z \xrightarrow{g} Y \to 0$ (check this by computing the Baer sum of these two extensions and verifying it splits)

Comment: (cont.) However, for $\lvert \text{Ext}^1 \rvert > 2$ we can't use this argument anymore, because even after taking the quotient of $\text{Ext}$ by $a \sim -a$ we will have more than one nontrivial class. In general, though, I agree that $\text{Ext}$ is a spookily powerful tool: that's why it's so popular and deeply studied! Anyway, the implication I was talking about was "if $M$ and $N$ are indecomposable then neither extension corresponds to the identity element of $\text{Ext}^1$". This is true, but only because we had also assumed $\text{Ext}^1 \neq 0$. Still very simple, but not immediate.

Comment: @Diracdeltafunk thank you so much. This all seems so much clearer ($Ext$ really is powerfu!l). So just to clarify, if $Ext(Y, X)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$ or $mathbb{Z}/3$ then any indecomposable modules that occur  in between $X, Y$ must be isomorphic (if the latter, then the exact sequences don't have to be equivalent, though) since they cant belong to the trivial class. Did you mean $|Ext^1|>3$ above, by the way?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was a typo! But that's exactly right.